# Receiving non-zero exit status when filling an array dynamically from user input

Tags: c, arrays, exit-code

```
#include <stdio.h>


  int main(void){

    int inputNumber;
    int counter=0;
    int totalValue;
    int arr[counter];
    int avg;

    puts("Please enter any number of positive whole numbers you would like to be averaged. Enter ' -1 ' when you are finished for your result.\n");

    while(scanf("%d\n", &arr[counter])){

      if(arr[counter] = -1){

        break;
      }
      if(arr[counter] > 0){

        totalValue += arr[counter];
        ++counter;

      }
      else if(arr[counter]<=0){

        puts("Please enter a positive number.");

      }
      else{

      }

    } 

    avg = totalValue/counter;
    printf("The average of your entered values is: %d", avg);
    return 0;
  }
```

I have attempted many things to try and stop it, and although this may come from a lack of knowledge is there really any way to do this other than creating an enormously large array?

I tried using a dynamic array with calloc() but i was met with the same errors. I am unsure what else is available as an option in this method.

The code is supposed to take the average of "n" user inputted values.

Comment: Use `realloc` after `malloc` or `calloc`.

Comment: If you just want to find the arithmetic mean of an arbitrary number of integers, there is no need to store all of the values.  All you need to keep track of is the sum and the number of entries.

Comment: But if you do, you'd better not allocate an array of length `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an array.

Quick & dirty but easier that you wanted to do

```
    int     number = 0;
    int     counter = 0;    
    int     total = 0;

    while (number != -1)
    {
        total += number;
        ++counter;
        scanf("%d", &number);
    }

    printf("average = %d\n", total / (counter - 1) );
```

Comment: Just that avg should be float not int

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky Yeah, the inputs can also be floating values, I guess it depends on what the author wants  :)